# How to use UML for describing distributed tasks

Tags: parallel-processing, uml, mpi, sequence-diagram

I am preparing a presentation and want to show some UML diagrams which will tell about how my distributed program runs. Since UML is a common language in the software world, I thought that it is one of the best ways to tell about the things in my mind to the listeners.

The problem is that I don't know how I can use UML diagrams for some distributed tasks. Firstly, I want to use Sequence diagrams and show the distributed components as actors. It looks possible. But, how can I demonstrate mpi_reduce_all function in this diagram? And, how can I demonstrate asynchronous communication and then synchronization (i.e. after a while I run isend/irecv commands, I synchronize the processes using wait_all function)?

Is there any idea for this? Or alternative diagrams to demonstrate what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Check [uml-diagrams.org: UML Activity Diagram Examples](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-examples.html). The [Fork/Join node in UML Activity Diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#fork-node) is explicitly designed to show parallel tasks and synchronization points.
2. For the purposes of a presentation consider [BPMN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation). The Business Process Model and
   Notation (`BPMN`) language is also common in the software world and is also backed by the Object Management Group (`OMG`).

Description of parallel tasks and data exchange and synchronization points is among it's strong features.

See also:

- [Bonitasoft: The Ultimate Guide to BPMN2](https://go.bonitasoft.com/ultimateguidebpmn-EN.pdf)